# Using an alternative sidebar when creating a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to load an alternative sidebar in a Wordpress theme I'm creating (I'm a novice, by the way). A very old answer on stackoverflow suggests creating a new sidebar and calling it something like sidebar_alt.php and altering the code as follows:

```
<?php get_sidebar('alt'); ?>
```

But that doesn't work for me, it just keeps loading the original sidebar. I read a different answer that said you have to register the alternative sidebar in the functions.php file. Do any of you very nice, smart and helpful people out there know if this is true? If so, what code would I have to add? Or is there another alternative (that doesn't include plugins)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As you mention in your question, you need to register the sidebar first - see [`register_sidebar` example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar#Example).

Comment: Sorry but I've been reading the Codex info and fiddling with the code for the last two hours and getting nowhere. There's way too much there that I just don't understand.

Comment: Finally put my head down and got it working, though I'm still not sure how. Thanks again for taking the time to advise.

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar

You have created sidebar file with name "sidebar_alt.php" which is wrong you should create it like `"sidebar-{name}.php"` `eg. "sidebar-alt.php".`